# jQuery Mobile 1.0a4.1 iPad Viewport Size

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, viewport

I just updated the jQuery Mobile version of our client book-in page to the latest 1.0a4.1 and I need some help debugging a window sizing issue off-site (I'm not on location).

The page runs on an iPad at the store so clients can book in their own cases. However, the page is being displayed like it's on an iPhone with huge lettering. "Emulating" with Ripple shows everything as it should, though.

I can't debug it from here and I'm not using any other CSS besides the base 1.0a4.1 stylesheets. How do I force jQuery Mobile to display the page as if on an iPad?

### Here is a screenshot sent by the store clerk:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 1. How was it displayed 2. Where's your code? 3. Do you expect me to guess it? :P

Comment: @naugtur, I didn't want to come off as "fix my code for me". I was hoping there was something non-obvious about the new alpha version (or maybe a bug). You can see it here: http://ifix.co.za/capetown/Case/ClientBookIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have the time to test it or try the fix, so it's still a guess, but at least based on your code inspection ;)

ok, so you put a `meta viewport` in your page and JQM also pops in a little 
`<meta content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">`.

As I said - I didn't test it, but I expect a collision. I have read somewhere that JQM was supposed to stop putting those metatags there... Try fiddling with that metatag a bit.
Also - see if the alpha4 or 4.1 release notes (on the blog) say something about viewports.

Comment: Ah ha! I found the culprit. It was a conflicting viewport meta tag: `<meta content="width=320, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />` that was forcing jQuery Mobile into small mode. I can't believe I missed this. The previous version of jQM was not affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

[Running Media Queries](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/mediahelpers.html)